# Fluids in motion and pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

We are taught in the lessons of fluid mechanics that for an ideal non compressible and non viscous fluid $at-rest$, the pressure at any point within the fluid is independent of the direction. But I want to know whether it is true for a fluid $in-motion$? If really it is true then how can this be explained.

Suppose a fluid is flowing ideally( steady) in a tube then at any point in space inside tube we choose, the value of pressure due to fluid  for the imaginary area element will be higher when its area vector will be parallel to the velocity of particles of fluid. In all the other cases particles will not strike the imaginary area element with full impact and hence it shows that pressure is not independent of direction! Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: It is not true for a fluid in motion. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_tube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fluid in motion possesses momentum, just like any massive body in motion. And if the momentum changes, for example if the fluid hits a plate as you suggest, then there will be a force defined by:

$$ F = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} $$

And remember that momentum is a vector, so the force we get by differentiating it is also a vector (obviously) and is dependant on direction. So the pressure in a system where the fluid is in motion will **not** be independant of direction. The pressure is only the same anywhere when the fluid is not changing momentum, which usually but not necessarily means it isn't moving.

Comment: So in the application of bernoulli equation why do we assume a term of $pressure$. It is confusing as $pressure$ just depends on $orientation$ we take hence the $pressure$ term just makes no sense at all. Hence we also cannot assign pressure at a point in the flow!

Comment: I think that in your answer last lines are more important.  It suggests that in a fluid flow taking a very small cross section in the pipe the pressure will be constant and hence a pressure can be assigned at that cross section! I think my problem is solved. Thank you.